# Difference between 化成品 - 化学品 - 化工品?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

Could you please explain me the difference between 化成品【かせいひん】 - 化学品【かがくひん】 - 化工品【かこうひん】, and if possible provide the appropriate translation of each word? 
All of them means "chemicals", but how I could distinguish them?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please check the title. 化工品 or 加工品?

Answer (score 2):

化学品 and 化成品 are one and the same both meaning chemicals. The online dictionary weblio says that 化学品　are also called 化成品。化工　is shorthand for 化学工学 or chemical engineering. So I would assume that 化工品 are items used in/by chemical engineers, but I cannot find an authoritative source confirming that.

Comment: You're using 化, 科 and 加 pretty inconsistently...Which one is correct?